# Non-english fonts (characters) insertion failed in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Being the hibernate properties set as follows,

```
 hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
 hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
 hibernate.connection.CharSet=UTF-8
```

and following tags been added to jsp page ,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset=UTF-8>
```

when I directly insert non English fonts and retrieve it from database, I could display the non English fonts in JSP page. But while getting input from view to model non English fonts ( characters ) are displayed as `?` and hence insertion fails.

Note : Database used is Mysql

Comment: What do you mean by non english characters ? You mean to say special characters ?

Comment: I am getting input in my native language which is not English

Comment: I am getting input in Tamil language.insertion succeeds but all chars are displayed as '?', but when i manually insert Tamil chars into database everything works fine.. the problem only being between view and model..

Comment: 'when i manually insert Tamil chars into database everything works fine' you mean to say it works proper on UI ?

Comment: yes its working fine on UI while manually inserted into table directly, the problem only being with the data got from view is displayed as '????????'

Comment: Use the debug statement of logger and check which layer convert the actual data into ????.

Comment: i altered the table properties and set the collation to utf8-utf-8_unicode_ci and engine to innoDB , Now everything is alright and working fine .. Thanks for your support @user2115021